# Sending email as per desired format in Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to send emails but it is not sending as per my desired format.
Can it be possible to send emails like this:-
[image]

Now my script is sending like this:-

> TF,Unfunded,Platform,Link,,TF,Unfunded,,Data,Link,Date,Round,Funds,Domain,,Date,Round,Fundings,Domain,Changes Made,,,,,,7-May-02,Incorporation,2037.41,Shaji Vadakke Parambath,Vinay Gupta,Add round,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

My code is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop like this. If you want to get a better response, in the future I would recommend giving us access to a spreadsheet that has data consistent with the example and access to the script editor.  It's difficult to copy code or data from an image. Which makes it less likely that someone will step up to help you.  It would also be appreciated if you would take a stab at the code yourself.  This code does work and I tested it with fake data.

This will comma separate all of the values in the row that it sends.  The last column must be empty to qualify for sending and the 8 column must not be blank.

```
function SendingEmails()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow=5;
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var subject='Your Subject';
  var emailaddress='Your Email Address';
  for(var i=startRow-1;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    if(!vA[i][vA[0].length-1] && vA[i][7])//not already sent and some data is available
    {
      //Logger.log('Send Mail: %s',formatAsTable(vA[i]));
      //var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(formatAsTable(vA[i]));
      //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Format As Table')
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddres,subject,vA[i].join(','))
      sh.getRange(i+1,vA[0].length).setValue('mailsent');
    }
  }
}

function formatAsTable(vA)
{
  var s='<style>table{border:1px solid #000;}th,td{border:1px solid #000;}"</style><table><tr>';
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length-1;i++)
  {
    s+='<td>' + vA[i] + '</td>';
  }
  s+='</tr></table>';
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, I really appreciate your valuable reply. The above code is a little bit tough for me. Please find the sheet link below.. I need the highlighted areas to be sent exactly as a table by email. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19K8vM99ftC23HnuSQqjIB8kZ-ulCLtoTffn6slxGdVI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hello Cooper, My Bad! I have not given permissions. Now I have done necessary changes. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay there it is for you.  Can you figure out the email address and the subject.

Comment: You wanted everything on that line separated by commas and that is exactly what vA[i].join(',') does. By the way I just changed the answer a bit.

Comment: Hey, I think there is a slight misunderstanding here.I don't need the data in comma separated format. I need it to the same table to be sent by email as it is showing in the spreadsheet that I have shared. will it be possible?

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Comment: Okay I think that's it.  The answer has changed there's two functions now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install SheetConverter (created by David Bingham (Mogsdad)). Google it and it gives great instructions on how to install the library. The, I modified the example given to this:

```
function example() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
 var conv = SheetConverter.init(ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
                            ss.getSpreadsheetLocale());
 // Grab an array for formatted content
 var array = conv.convertRange(range);
   // Get a html table version, with all formatting
  var html = conv.convertRange2html(range);
  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 'Daily report','' ,{htmlBody: html})
}
```

It sent a test I set up of your data perfectly.

Comment: Hello Nelson, Thanks! But when I am running my script it is taking too long time. In another hand, Google is warning to go in the fever of the library as it is not a verified code.